# Flutter fill Column with items evenly

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, widget

I have a simple `Column` with 2 `Containers` and a `SizedBox` inside of it. I simply would like to have the `SizedBox` in the middle of them and the Containers should fill fill the space above/below. I can achieve that by setting the `height` but that is not dynamic and it **needs to be dynamic**.

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

And my `code`:

```
Column(
  children: [
    // counter_container
    Container(
      width: detailContainerWidth,
      height: detailContainerHeight,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: const Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
          )),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: spacingBetweenViews,
    ),
    // price_container
    Container(
      width: detailContainerWidth,
      height: detailContainerHeight,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomRight:
                const Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
          )),
    )
  ],
)
```

Is there a way to make this *dynamically* instead of setting the `height` of the two `Containers`?

Comment: Please ,what do you mean by dynamic here ?

Comment: @KabirouAgouda I simply don't want to give a `height` to the containers but they should fill the width and height themselfes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself. Let me know if there is a *better*  way to get this done, but my is working so I a fine with it for now:

```
  Flexible(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // counter_container
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight:
                        const Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
                  )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: spacingBetweenViews,
          ),
          // price_container
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomRight:
                        const Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
                  )),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that `Flexible` Widgets are `FlexFit.loose` by default. If you want the green and the blue containers to be always the same height, regardless of their content, you should use `FlexFit.tight`, or the `Expanded` Widget.

`Expanded` is just `Flexible` with `FlexFit.tight`. [[more info]](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

With `Flexible`:

[image]

With `Expanded`:

[image]

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        // counter_container
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              ),
              child:
                  (Text('HAHAHA\nHAHAHA\nHAHAHA\nHAHAHA\nHAHAHA\nHAHAHA\n'))),
        ),

        SizedBox(
          height: 8.0,
        ),
        // price_container
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

*Note: I also added `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to your `Column` so that your container fill the width of the screen.*